# Facebook authentification forbidden

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, authentication, asp.net-core

Faced issue with facebook authentication which starts a few months ago, the error is: `"Error from RemoteAuthentication: An error occurred when retrieving Facebook user information (Forbidden). Please check if the authentication information is correct and the corresponding Facebook Graph API is enabled.."`. Sometimes it is hard to reproduce and external login could work after 2nd or 3rd  times on button submit click.

Here is my code from startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"))
                        {
                            context.Response.Clear();
                            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    };

                })
                .AddFacebook(options =>
                {
                    options.AppId = Configuration["Facebook:AppKey"];
                    options.AppSecret = Configuration["Facebook:AppSecret"];
                    options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/account/login");
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                })
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = Configuration["Google:AppKey"];
                    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Google:AppSecret"];
                    options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/account/login");
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                });
```

And from controller:

```
[HttpGet("/account/login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string error = "", string returnUrl = "", string errorStateKey = null, string errorStateMessage = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            Request.QueryString.Add("ReturnUrl", returnUrl);
        }
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            // Check if ReturnUrl is Wp Support Site Url>>
            var isAbsoluteReturnUrl = IsAbsoluteValidUrl(returnUrl);
            if (!isAbsoluteReturnUrl) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            var uriWpReturn = new Uri(returnUrl);
            var hostWpReturn = uriWpReturn.Host;

            var uriWp = new Uri(_wpOptions.Value.Host);
            var hostWp = uriWp.Host;
            if (hostWpReturn == hostWp)
            {
                returnUrl = string.Format(_wpOptions.Value.AutologinUrl, CurrentSalesPeople.Var1, returnUrl);
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            // << check if ReturnUrl is Wp Support Site


            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            ViewData["Error"] = error;
        }
        if (errorStateKey != null && errorStateMessage != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(errorStateKey, errorStateMessage);
        }
        return await ShowLoginViewAsync(null);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return await ShowLoginViewAsync(model);

        var validatePeople = await _authService.ValidateSalespeople(model.Login, model.Password);
        if (!validatePeople.Success)
        {
            var errorStateKey = "Password";
            var errorStateMessage = validatePeople.Message;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { returnUrl = model.ReturnUrl, errorStateKey = errorStateKey, errorStateMessage = errorStateMessage });
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(errorStateKey, errorStateMessage);
            return await ShowLoginViewAsync(model);
        }
        var salespeopleRole = await _roleService.GetRoleNameBySalespeopleId(validatePeople.Model.SId);
        if (!salespeopleRole.Success)
        {
            var errorStateKey = "";
            var errorStateMessage = validatePeople.Message;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { returnUrl = model.ReturnUrl, errorStateKey = errorStateKey, errorStateMessage = errorStateMessage });
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(errorStateKey, errorStateMessage);
            return await ShowLoginViewAsync(model);
        }
        var requestForDealerToolkit = await _dealerService.GetToolkitTypeBySalespeopleIddAsync(validatePeople.Model.SId);
        if (!requestForDealerToolkit.Success)
        {
            var errorStateKey = "";
            var errorStateMessage = "Problem with your toolkit subscription. Please tell a support about this error";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { returnUrl = model.ReturnUrl, errorStateKey = errorStateKey, errorStateMessage = errorStateMessage });
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(errorStateKey, errorStateMessage);
            return await ShowLoginViewAsync(model);
        }
        var getToolkit = GetToolkitTypeForSalespeople(validatePeople.Model.SubscriptionTypeId, requestForDealerToolkit.Model);

        var roleName = new RoleHelper(getToolkit, salespeopleRole.Model == "Manager").RoleName;
        if (roleName == "None")
        {
            var errorStateKey = "Password";
            var errorStateMessage = "You don't have permissions";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { returnUrl = model.ReturnUrl, errorStateKey = errorStateKey, errorStateMessage = errorStateMessage });
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(errorStateKey, errorStateMessage);
            return await ShowLoginViewAsync(model);
        }

        //We clear session before each login to prevent caching changes in new app vesrions 
        //HttpContext.Session.Clear();

        await Authenticate(validatePeople.Model, roleName, getToolkit);


        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
    }

    private async Task<IActionResult> ShowLoginViewAsync(object model)
    {
        var schemeProvider = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>();
        var shemas = await schemeProvider.GetAllSchemesAsync().FromAsyncResult(z => z.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Facebook") || x.Name.Equals("Google")).ToList());
        ViewBag.Shemas = shemas;
        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string extReturnUrl = null)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = extReturnUrl });
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
        var externalModel = ExternalLoginModel.FromIdentity(HttpContext);

        if (externalModel != null)
        {
            var user = default(Salespeople);
            if (externalModel.Provider.Equals("Google"))
            {
                var request = await _salespeopleGetService.GetSalespeopleByPredicateAsNoTrackingAsync(p => p.GoogleKey.Equals(externalModel.Id));
                if (!request.Success)
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", new { error = "You do not have a connected google account", returnUrl = returnUrl });
                user = request.Model;
            }
            else if (externalModel.Provider.Equals("Facebook"))
            {
                var request = await _salespeopleGetService.GetSalespeopleByPredicateAsNoTrackingAsync(p => p.FacebookKey.Equals(externalModel.Id));
                if (!request.Success)
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", new { error = "You do not have a connected facebook account", returnUrl = returnUrl });
                user = request.Model;
            }
            return await Login(new LoginModel() { Login = user?.Email, Password = user?.Pass, ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }



    private async Task Authenticate(Salespeople user, string role, int toolkitType)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.SId.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String),
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData,toolkitType.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expiration, "")
        };
        ClaimsIdentity id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
            ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
        _cpl = new ClaimsPrincipal(id);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, _cpl, (await _authService.GetAuthenticationPropertiesWithPermissions(user)).Model);
    }
```

From logs, the challenge for external login was completed but in the end it was failed with forbidden error. I saw some several issues which were similar to mine but they didn't help me. Is there any possible solution to solve it?

Adding debug output logs if it could help, first one is unsuccess authentication and second one is succeed. This for same user but I don't know it have different flow for authentication

```
--- failing ---
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5151/signin-facebook?code=AQDIS9CjmtoflJKzLhcwuPS0PvpcbuTYl_oq_0ZB1ykskn_yg8OezWJO2xQfvGGNulUDGK7hYu4kzPRRfXP5f04df-LbjSsWas7TuZJjD5_3dczQwtyNmkMUbLuE5l2pRLy8moqozj5ypljQdGeIxzh_ybho0jWifiYBibbzPYLSeER011pf9JR1PfRpVhI0hn3X7bQ-zz2lxTXLie4maGlIVPNKMg5e2g8U58Oj-8VVDghl4_A_yrfvadBhV4-WAWZ2pgdMgWU8cQC17MqxVDB6BPN75ptKM2aTVLftETZ_E5IFc2PYPyXncimU0XX0Ql7Tsx6ocTTsc-oJUMpSdUzx&state=CfDJ8DnbIAZdrZlOiRhsuDkovd9SFo8MwSuyOiFKGRVY9FUq03sttM2gpjCiozY40SvQNEuuoDhyWnw45lXPAUHdNAwKdqJcDRBjuTFoG3C5YiIsBX0Jde-broqU4tioNsTFZAxFxb1xzhsXkrRJsphH65yOPgbJlINl0MlHbt3M5olCCnbw1OTWt5MZMRugWyQ_si69LvVnrs2Si4-a2CajTwQvFck0xgqwhagoXYljz-R4bg2uKN2hpoXioA3SoXS83A  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook.FacebookHandler:Information: Error from RemoteAuthentication: An error occurred when retrieving Facebook user information (Forbidden). Please check if the authentication information is correct and the corresponding Facebook Graph API is enabled..
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 294.3243ms 302 
--- failing ---

--- not failing ---
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 19326.7074ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5151/signin-facebook?code=AQBRqh3qYM3FEikkxFKq_x4mX8S4XT0YzKwE9rvxIp3o3l70B9wkF1HZPkCxS-rQMwc2ETIr52BtTou520X0MxfHvSTQUK_JHRbgF5Hsk4cfzgUVHn0ypnhL4K18hd1_cLDsoWRBA1XAMz6zhMY7dzsm0pinXT_Y3vh2L-lBDlNThqgcNkWMs1yxbzSCZ9H8qq8ZuqqbTg1QBRuO0szuUG0_IDVl6CRqNfRnljzd2QA9SOX_KgocTA7jW8K_LPLlei_tEDxN0BXYYRTtv0tuDNoAHdcT0HrztxfDAtvoETesfJDUS0CJ21-4D7wnUvJ5_FXyJNVnbfUf6d3EC7mb5Osw&state=CfDJ8DnbIAZdrZlOiRhsuDkovd9Mt0AE6FLYwOyW7VgwOkat4BDyy6Dzfs19-26jZy48Z_x7nqOfA40UemgGkzZ-fzZfEvmXcMSw2XVNbk_ruIEsbG15K0Dwp5Bu5Ntdl1smvFirlUPlofXdOAlV8TTnakjACy4RgHy-qQ2oYmGkLlamfC_lvz2rhMboMx-6UYJY3GqpMiar4LlTmRTeD_crFAUtvTLWDiQFzJLavbHghn5U8DjFWCudkhmnq_DPolxJMA  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
--- not failing ---
```

Comment: Do you mean that your code has errors sometimes and others work well?What have you tried?As the error has said,do you enable the Facebook Graph API?

Comment: @XingZou I mean that it could login after 2nd or 3rd time click on facebook without errors, or could it works from the first click on it. The only error is from console is higher in the topic with forbidden access. Where I can enable the Graph api? I Tried to find in my created facebook application, but I didn't find it.